# Server establishing authenticity again

Tags: ssh

The first time I tried to connect to my server through SSH, I received this message:

```
The authenticity of host 'hostname' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is <finger print>
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

which is perfectly normal. I know its only shown on the first time you connect to the server. However, now 8 months later I got the same message. Is this normal?

No changes took place on my machine such as updates or deleting/modifying any files (at least by me).

I wanted to double check that this is not something bad going on on the server. If hopefully is not something bad, what other reasons cause that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how the host keys are stored in the `known_hosts` file, if you access the server on a slightly different name (eg., a shorter domain name because you set up a search domain, or a new domain because you've changed DNS, a new IP, etc.), then you will get this prompt again.

In other words,

```
$ ssh myserver.example.com
```

is treated differently from

```
$ ssh myserver
```

or

```
$ ssh 10.0.0.1
```

even if they all resolve to the same place.

This doesn't indicate anything bad (or anything not-bad); it does mean that you won't get a warning about the host key changing (which *would* be the sign of something bad), because it will be treated as a new host entry.

[This question on the UNIX Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31549/is-it-possible-to-find-out-the-hosts-in-the-known-hosts-file) has some more useful information about `known_hosts` that you might find helpful.